# ASP.NET Profile doesn't persist data

Tags: asp.net, profile

I'm trying to use ASP.NET Profile to persist user data with default `machine.config` (.Net Framework 4.5.2) to web.config Site's  was added only.

```
    <system.web>
      <profile>
        <properties>
          <add name="AddressInfo" type="UserAddress" serializeAs="Binary"/>
        </properties>
      </profile>
    </system.web>
```

I tested it by simple code-behind (on Page 3 TextBox and Button)

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    GetUserAddress();
  }
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Database writes happening here!
    Profile.AddressInfo.City = txtCity.Text;
    Profile.AddressInfo.Street = txtStreetAddress.Text;
    Profile.AddressInfo.State = txtState.Text;

    // Get settings from database.
    GetUserAddress();
  }

  private void GetUserAddress()
  {
    // Database reads happening here!
    lblUserData.Text = String.Format("You live here: {0}, {1}, {2}",
      Profile.AddressInfo.Street, Profile.AddressInfo.City,
      Profile.AddressInfo.State);
  }
}
[Serializable]
public class UserAddress
{
  public string Street = string.Empty;
  public string City = string.Empty;
  public string State = string.Empty;
}
```

Application started, "OnClick" without errors executes the methods (`btnSubmit_Click(...)` and `GetUserAddress()`) and updating value of `lblUserData` Label, but is nothing write to DB (also didn't created the DB itself - ASPNETDB.mdf in App_Data folder Site's). After reopen Page corresponding Profile properties and `lblUserData` Label was empty.

Answer (score 0):

I found root of issue. By default all users logging to Site as anonymous user (I didn't include "logging code"). By default anonymous user can't use the ASP.Net Profile for persist it data to storage. "Set()" request for particular properties is worked OK, values save to some temporary buffer, but doesn't save to storage. The Problem is deciding simple, you must add to `web.config` or `machine.config` the next:

```
<system.web>
      <anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />
</system.web>
```

and include `allowAnonymous="true"` parameter to every defined property (in `web.config`), like that:

```
        <properties>
          <add name="AddressInfo" type="UserAddress" serializeAs="Binary" allowAnonymous="true"/>
        </properties>
```

**OR didn't use** the anonymous users.

P.S> `ASPNETDB.mdf` in App_Data folder Site's are created automatically at first time use.